# C# event with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, events, arguments

How to make multiple arguments more than two? CustomButtonClickEventArgs is shared by many places, I don't want to modify. How to append ActiveRow and ActiveCol arguments which indicated the ComboBox location in a Grid into the ComboBoxCustomButtonClick event like below what I 'expected'?

```
private void MyUC1_ComboBoxCustomButtonClick(object sender, MyUC.CustomButtonClickEventArgs e, int ActiveRow, int ActiveCol)
```

declares:

```
public class CustomButtonClickEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly int Index;

        public readonly string Key;

        public readonly string Tag;

        public readonly Keys ModifierKeys;

        public CustomButtonClickEventArgs(int index, string key, string tag, Keys modifierKeys)
        {
            this.Index = index;
            this.Key = key;
            this.Tag = tag;
            this.ModifierKeys = modifierKeys;
        }
    }

public delegate void CustomButtonClickEventHandler(object sender, CustomButtonClickEventArgs e);
```

[ComboBox located in Grid Cell(1,1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpwO9.png)

Comment: Could you add a decorator/wrapper to CustomButtonClickEventArgs that added the ActiveRow and ActiveCol arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just defined the Event Arguments (EventArgs). What you need is a delegate that defines how the method should look.

Maybe something like this?

```
public delegate void CustomButtonClickEventHandler(object sender,
                                                   MyUC.CustomButtonClickEventArgs e,
                                                   int ActiveRow,
                                                   int ActiveCol);
```

When you define the event it needs this delegate:

```
public event CustomButtonClickEventHandler ComboBoxCustomButtonClick;
```

Comment: The new CustomButtonClickEventHandler works for multiple arguments. I used to put only 2 arguments. Now I knew it can be more numbers. Answer accepted.

Comment: It is basically a blueprint for a method definition.

Answer (score 0):

my new CustomButtonClickEventHandler defined as the below.

```
public delegate void ComboBoxCustomButtonClickEventHandler(object Sender, int ComboBoxCol, int ActiveRow, int ActiveCol, CustomButtonClickEventArgs e);

[Category("ComboBox"), Description("Occurs when a custom button of the ComboBox is clicked.")]
public event ComboBoxCustomButtonClickEventHandler ComboBoxCustomButtonClick;
```